# Why are two different hard drives listed as one disk in Disk Management?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, disk-management

I feel like there's something going wrong with my hard drives on my computer... Yesterday two I use for storage (M: and H:) stopped working altogether. Today they came back and seem fine, but now I just noticed that they're listed as **DISK 1** in Disk Management.

What's going on? Why are two different physical drives, which two different drive letters, listed under "DISK 1", and is this something I need to change?

[image]

**Note: I'm not talking about my RAID array!**

Comment: Your screenshot gave out some clues. Both disk are Dynamic. And Documents (G:) Layout is Mirror. You have somehow set both disk to mirror each other (RAID1?). So yes it looks like you lose 50% capacity (lose 1 HDD capacity), but you have a bit of extra redundancy (if either Disk2, or Disk3 fails, you still have a perfect copy).

Comment: @Darius I've made my question clearer. I'm not interested in the RAID array.

Comment: Sorry I guess I was a bit confused. Each "Disk" are often referring to a physical disk, so Disk1 is basically a 3TB Physical Disk, which have been separated into 2 partitions (2TB and 1TB respectively). M and H are not in a separate physical disk. You can try to confirm this by booting to your BIOS to see what does the BIOS see, and confirm if there are actually a physical 3TB HDD. Note: If you have a physical RAID card (not RAID inside windows), they can make multiple HDD visible as a single HDD under windows.

Comment: @Darius *facepalm* I completely forgot something: I used to have four harddrives. I switched two out for one, and created a partition on the old one that mirrored one of the old harddrives. I was thinking that that the new HD was M: and I still had the old one (H:). Doh!

Comment: Good to know you solved it. For sake of completeness can you summarise your comment ^ as an answer and accept it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather silly. I forgotten I'd removed a harddrive and replaced it, exactly as it was, as a partition on another.

I was baffled as to how Windows could see two different physical disks as one drive. Very much my bad.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: This refers to disks 2/3 in op's original screenshot.

It probably is two different physical disks. In Windows 8+ dynamic disks can span multiple physical drives, yet still be addressed with one drive letter:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-vista/what-are-basic-and-dynamic-disks

> Dynamic disks can contain a large number of dynamic volumes (approximately 2000) that function like the primary partitions used on basic disks. **In some versions of Windows, you can combine separate dynamic hard disks into a single dynamic volume (called spanning), split data among several hard disks (called striping)** for increased performance, or duplicate data among several hard disks (called mirroring) for increased reliability.

Comment: I've updated my question. I think it was originally confusing, making it sound like I was wondering about my RAID array, which I'm not. Thanks.